# Error "A number should have been here; I inserted '0'" appears when citing

Tags: biblatex, citing, biber, biblatex-chicago, biblatex-philosophy

I'm working to customize my own citation style so it complies with the one used at my university, and I think I got that right. The problem is that every time I try to cite I get the error: "A number should have been here; I inserted '0'".

When I change the style from `philosophy-verbose` to `biblatex-chicago` the error disappears, but obviously changes the style of my citations. I've tried every single thing to make this work, but I can't seem to fix it. What can I do?

Curiously, the error occurs only in the first citation, not in the other citations. But it's not due to being on the section title because I tried moving it, but the error still shows.

Here's my code (the error show's up where the `\autocites` occur):

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{report}

\usepackage[
    inner=4cm,
    outer=3cm,
    bindingoffset=.5cm,
    top=2.5cm,
    bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage[backend=biber,
            style=philosophy-verbose,
            autocite=footnote,
            isbn=false,
            giveninits=true,
            idemtracker=context,
            ibidtracker=context,
            loccittracker=context,
            opcittracker=context,
            citetracker=context,
            latinemph=true,
            commacit=false,
            scauthors=all,
            lowscauthors=false,
            annotation=true,
            classical=true,
            singletitle=false,
            editionformat=superscript,
            shorthandintro=true,
            %volumeformat=romansc,
            %library=true,
            hyperref,
            %backref,
            sorting=cst, % if one wants to implement a custom sorting of reference list
            lowscauthors=false]{biblatex}
%\usepackage[backend=biber,autocite=footnote,isbn=false,giveninits=true,idemtracker=context,ibidtracker=context,loccittracker=context,opcittracker=context,citetracker=context,annotation=true,singletitle=false,sorting=cst]{biblatex-chicago}
\usepackage[style=english]{csquotes}
\usepackage[bottom, hang, stable]{footmisc}
%\usepackage{libertine}
%\usepackage{Alegreya}
\usepackage[bitstream-charter]{mathdesign}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}

\DeclareFieldFormat[article, book, inbook, incollection, inproceedings, misc, thesis, unpublished]{title}{\textit{#1}} 

\addbibresource{thesis-bibliography.bib}

\setlength\parindent{0.5cm}

% Configuro l'indice in modo che mi mostri solo le sottosezioni, e non tutto

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{2}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}

%\frontmatter % Use roman page numbering style (i, ii, iii, iv...) for the pre-content pages
\pagestyle{plain}
            
\NewBibliographyString{opcited}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{%
    %idem = {\textsc{Id}\adddot},
    idem = {\textsc{Idem}},
    %ibidem = {ibid\adddot},
    ibidem = {Ibidem},
    %loccit = {},
    opcit = {},
    opcited = {},
}

\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamefamily}[1]{\textsc{#1}}

%%%%%%% STILE ANNALES %%%%%
%% in corsivo tutti i titoli
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{title}{\mkbibemph{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat[incollection]{title}{\mkbibemph{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat[inbook]{title}{\mkbibemph{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat[inreference]{title}{\mkbibemph{#1}}
%% in corsivo tutti i titoli
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{citetitle}{\mkbibemph{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat[incollection]{citetitle}{\mkbibemph{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat[inbook]{citetitle}{\mkbibemph{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat[inreference]{citetitle}{\mkbibemph{#1}}
%% riviste tra virgolette caporali
\DeclareFieldFormat{journaltitle}{\mkbibquote{#1}}

%%% TOGLI P. E PP.
%\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{%
%   page             = {},
%   pages            = {},
%} 

%% TOGLI LA VIRGOLA DOPO L'ANNO NEGLI ARTICOLI
\renewbibmacro{issue+date}{%
    \printtext[parens]{%
        \iffieldundef{issue}
        {\usebibmacro{date}}
        {\printfield{issue}%
            \setunit*{\addspace}%
            \usebibmacro{date}}}%
    \nopunct\newunit}
    
%% TOGLI LA VIRGOLA DOPO IL VOLUME e metti un /
\renewbibmacro*{volume+number+eid}{%
    \printfield{volume}%
    \setunit*{\addslash}% DELETED
    %  \setunit*{\addcolon}% ADDED
    \printfield{number}%
    \setunit{\space}%
    \printfield{eid}}
    
%% TOGLI LA VIRGOLA DOPO JOURNAL TITLE
\renewbibmacro*{journal+issuetitle}{%
    \usebibmacro{journal}%
    \setunit*{\addspace}%
    \iffieldundef{series}
    {}
    {\newunit
        \printfield{series}%
        \setunit{\addspace}}%
    \usebibmacro{volume+number+eid}%
    \setunit{\addspace}%
    \usebibmacro{issue+date}%
    \setunit{\addcolon\space}%
    \usebibmacro{issue}%
    \newunit}
    
%\renewbibmacro*{publisher+location+date}{%
%  \printfield{publisher}%
%  \iffieldundef{location}
%    {\setunit*{\addcomma\space}}
%    {\setunit*{\addcolon\space}}%
%  \printfield{location}%
%  \setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
%  \usebibmacro{date}%
%  \newunit}

%% Remove vol. 
\DeclareFieldFormat[book]{volume}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat[reference]{volume}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat[collection]{volume}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat[incollection]{volume}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat[inbook]{volume}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat[inreference]{volume}{#1}

%% Series volumes in Roman capital letters
\DeclareFieldFormat[book]{number}{\RN{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat[reference]{number}{\RN{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat[collection]{number}{\RN{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat[inbook]{number}{\RN{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat[inreference]{number}{\RN{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat[incollection]{number}{\RN{#1}}

%% Ordina bibliografia per autore, serie, volume, numero, anno, titolo
\DeclareSortingTemplate{cst}{%
    \sort{
        \field{author}
        \field{editor}
        \field{translator}
    }
    \sort{
        \field{series}
        \field{journal}
    }
    \sort{
        \field{volume}
    }
    \sort{
        \field{number}
    }
    \sort{
        \field{title}
    }
    \sort{
    \field{year}
    }   
}

\AtEveryCitekey{\clearfield{pages}}

\setlength{\footnotemargin}{5mm}
\addtolength{\footnotesep}{1.5mm}

\usepackage{relsize,etoolbox}
\AtBeginEnvironment{quotation}{\smaller}

\begin{document}

    %\mainmatter
    
    \titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\scshape\Large}
    {\MakeUppercase{\chaptertitlename} \thechapter}
    {-12pt}{\bfseries\LARGE}
    
    \renewcommand{\thechapter}{\Roman{chapter}}
    
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    
    \renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{%
        \markboth{#1}{}
    }
    
    \chapter[Peter Strawson: The Analytical Metaphysician]{Peter Strawson: The Analytical\\ Metaphysician}

    \section{Life \& Works \autocites[This section maps Peter Strawson's profile based on his autobiographies:][]{strawson_intellectualautobiography} {strawson_bitintellectualautobiography}}
    
    \setstretch{1.25}
    
    Sir Peter Frederick Strawson was born on 23 November 1919 in Ealing, London. Second son to Cyril Walter Strawson (1888-1936) and Nellie Dora Jewell (1890-1975). His older brother was John Strawson, and Galen and Margaret followed him. Both his parents were school teachers... 
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, we cannot run your example as is because we don't have the relevant entries from your file `thesis-bibliography.bib`. If I use a file that I have (`biblatex-examples.bib`, which is installed on all systems with `biblatex`) and cite entries from that file (`sigfridsson` and `worman`) I get no error.

Comment: Any news here? As mentioned in my comment above, I failed to reproduce your error with the code provided in the question. Please share the relevant entries from your `.bib` file with us so that we can reproduce the issue.